# How do your get fractional seconds from Howard Hinnant date

Tags: c++, date, std

Example: Parsing date / time from string then I want to break down the components of the date/time.. It seems I get all but I am stuck on the fractional seconds. Code follows

```
std::wistringstream in{ L"2016-12-11 15:43:22.0999919" };
date::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds> tp;
in >> date::parse(L"%F %T", tp);
assert(!in.fail());
assert(!in.bad());

date::sys_days dp = date::floor<date::days>(tp);
date::year_month_day the_date = date::year_month_day{ dp };
date::time_of_day<std::chrono::microseconds> the_time = date::make_time(tp - dp);
std::cout << the_date << ' ' << the_time << std::endl;

std::cout << "Year: " << the_date.year() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Month: " << (unsigned)the_date.month() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Date: " << the_date.day() << std::endl;

std::cout << "Hour: " << the_time.hours().count() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Minutes: " << the_time.minutes().count() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Seconds: " << the_time.seconds().count() << std::endl;
```

// the following is incorrect

```
std::cout << "Micro Seconds: " << the_time.microseconds().count() << std::endl;
```

error C2039: 'microseconds': is not a member of 'date::time_of_day'

Comment: what's incorrect is there?

Comment: 'microseconds()' is not a member of 'date::time_of_day<std::chrono::microseconds>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, just got the edit.

Correct, `microseconds` is not a member of `date::time_of_day`.  The [documentation](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html#time_of_day) for `time_of_day<Duration>` gives this synopsis when `Duration` has sub-second precision:

```
time_of_day<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>
{
public:
    using precision = The decimal-based duration used to format

    constexpr time_of_day() noexcept;
    constexpr explicit time_of_day(std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> since_midnight) noexcept;

    constexpr std::chrono::hours   hours() const noexcept;
    constexpr std::chrono::minutes minutes() const noexcept;
    constexpr std::chrono::seconds seconds() const noexcept;
    constexpr precision subseconds() const noexcept;
    constexpr unsigned mode() const noexcept;

    constexpr explicit operator precision() const noexcept;
    constexpr precision to_duration() const noexcept;

    void make24() noexcept;
    void make12() noexcept;
};
```

If I change:

```
the_time.microseconds().count()
```

to:

```
the_time.subseconds().count()
```

Then the output I get is:

```
2016-12-11 15:43:22.099992
Year: 2016
Month: 12
Date: 11
Hour: 15
Minutes: 43
Seconds: 22
Micro Seconds: 99992
```

Is this what you're getting?  If it is, you're getting the correct answer.  If you're not getting this, please tell us what you *are* seeing.  Bugs happen, and I appreciate bug reports and try to fix them as quickly as possible.

If this *is* what you're seeing, and you don't believe it is correct, you may be confused by the rounding.  You are reading in 7 decimal fractional digits, and then asking for that to be rounded to 6 decimal fractional digits.  If you desire the full precision of the timestamp in the string, you will need to use a unit at least as fine as 100ns, for example:

```
date::sys_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds> tp;
// ...
auto the_time = date::make_time(tp - dp);
// ...
std::cout << "Nanoseconds: " << the_time.subseconds().count() << std::endl;
```

And the output now ends with:

```
Nanoseconds: 99991900
```

**Update**

The rationale for the name `subseconds` as opposed to the more obvious name `microseconds` is that the `precision` (and thus the return type) of this member is too varied for me to give a more precise name to return the fractional seconds.  It could be `nanoseconds` as demonstrated above.  Or it could even be something crazy like [`microfortnights`](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#microfortnights).

In the comments below when I noted that this question found a bug.  It turns out when I tried to parse `microfortnights` I got a compile-time error, which I've just fixed.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. BTW is SO the right forum for questions on this library?

Comment: Glad I could help.  And you helped me too.  In answering your question I found a bug.  Fixing it now, and will update my answer with that info shortly.

Comment: SO is fine for questions about my date lib.  There are also facilities on GitHub site such as the issues list and the gitter chat.  Whatever you are comfortable with is fine with me.